# Code listing in subfigure

Tags: listings, verbatim, subfloats

I am trying to use the `subfigure` package of LaTeX to display a code listing.  Here was my first attempt:

```
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[Standard approach]{
  {\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
var caps = new Capabilities(Messaging);
\end{verbatim}
  }
}
\subfigure[Emerson approach] {
  \includegraphics[width=3in]{fig/trust-emerson}
}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
```

(All I did was change code where I would have put an `\includegraphics` line into text.)

I've also tried the equivalent idea using the `listings` package and replacing the lines in the subfigure with

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Code
\end{lstlisting}
```

But that also didn't compile.

Comment: What is the error given by LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is a clash of the `subfigure` and `verbatim` packages. One workaround can be the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}[]{VerbEnv}
var caps = new Capabilities(Messaging);
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[Standard approach]{
\BUseVerbatim[fontshape=it,fontsize=\footnotesize,fontfamily=courier]{VerbEnv}
}
\subfigure[Emerson approach] {
\includegraphics[width=2in]{fig.eps}
}
\caption{caption }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For details see the documentation for the `fancyvrb` package.