# Code listing in subfigure using lstlisting

Tags: floats, listings, subfloats

I am trying to use the subfigure package of LaTeX to display a piece of SQL code. The purpose is similar to [Code listing in subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23021/code-listing-in-subfigure), but I'd like syntax highlighting using `lstlisting` environment rather than `verbatim`. Here is what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
  \subfigure[Query 1]{
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL]
      SELECT * FROM Table;
    \end{lstlisting}
  }
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile since the subfigure and verbatim packages clash. The linked post suggests a workaround for the `verbatim` environment, but what if I'd like to use `lstlisting`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Box the listing using a `lrbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\newbox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL]
SELECT * FROM Table;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{table*}
\subfigure[Query 1]{\usebox\mybox}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `subfigure` is an obsolete package; you should use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead. Your code using `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\newbox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL]
SELECT * FROM Table;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{table*}
\subfloat[Query 1]{\usebox\mybox}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I can accept only in 5 minutes.